# How much damage is changing the user on fpm/pool.d/website-name.conf NGINX

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ftp

I have changed the user under the file /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/website-name.conf

```
user = ftplatinopeeyush
group = ftplatinopeeyush
```

Only those parameters were changed on that file. The following line I didn't touch it.

```
listen = /var/run/user-name.sock
```

**Why Did I change this parameters?**

I created a FTP user and changed the ownership of the webfiles to this user so I can upload files to the Server but then wordpress said that the files were not writable.

Now after changing the user on the pool.d/website-name.conf file i can upload files thru filezilla (with the FTP user) and also upload plugins via wordpress dashboard.

[image]

Everything seems to be working just fine but could this affect something else on my site or on the Nginx server?

How can I create a FTP user that allows me to upload files to my server without having file permission issues in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically did the right thing already: created a separate Linux user and run PHP-FPM pool with that user. You then manage the website files in SFTP with the same user.

If you follow through ["NGINX and PHP-FPM. What my permissions should be?"](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be), there's one extra step. That is, ensuring that your NGINX web user is a member of your PHP usergroup:

```
usermod -a -G ftplatinopeeyush www-data
```

What this achieves, is that NGINX can read any files of your website, which have group permission set to readable. E.g. chmod 0750 on all directories and 0640 on all files will allow NGINX to read all your website files.

Further, you will be able to easily control which files are sensitive and should not be served by NGINX by simply removing the read permission for group, e.g. by setting chmod 0600 on wp-config.php or a similar sensitive file.

Answer (score -1):

Btw it looks like about user permission (not owned by fpm users), please take a look into the config files of nginx & php-fpm ( current example we used nginx) and the user is `ftplatinopeeyush`

### CHECK

1. Check your files / wordpress user permissions, make sure your wordpress user are `ubuntu` (you can check with `ls -l`), and make sure your file placed on user home directory : `/home/ftplatinopeeyush` (or anywhere home directory and it was writable by the `ftplatinopeeyush` user)
2. go to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
   check the parameter `user`, please make sure the user is `www-data`

example:

```
user www-data; # < this

worker_processes auto;
# ... next config
```

3. And then go to `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/website-name.conf`
   and check the configurations about:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

4. (fpm) user & group (wordpress files owned user)

```
user=ftplatinopeeyush
group=ftplatinopeeyush
```

### CASE

1. fpm : `listen.owner` & `listen.group` should match with nginx: `user`
2. fpm: `user` & `group` should be match with wordpress / root user.
3. Permission: wordpress file placed on directory that writable by user

### RESOLVE

Before start, please make sure you have super admin privileges (root user)

1. Check your user home directory:

- command

```sh
cat /etc/passwd | grep ftplatinopeeyush
```

- output (where the `/home/ftplatinopeeyush` is home directory)

`NameOfUser:x:1234:1234:NameOfUser:/home/ftplatinopeeyush:`

2. Place your wordpress (document root) to your home directory. (eg: `/home/ftplatinopeeyush/pathtowordpress`)
3. Fix the owner

```sh
chown -R ftplatinopeeyush:ftplatinopeeyush /home/ftplatinopeeyush/pathtowordpress
```

4. Set the permission (644 to files and 755 to directory)

- set files permission

```sh
find /home/ftplatinopeeyush/pathtowordpress -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

- set directories permission

```sh
find /home/ftplatinopeeyush/pathtowordpress -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

5. Change your nginx user to `www-data`

```sh
nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

change variable `user` to `www-data`
6. Change configuration of `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/website-name.conf`

```sh
nano /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/website-name.conf
```

make sure the variable `user` & `group` are `ftplatinopeeyush`
and variable `listen.owner` & `listen.group` are `www-data`

or example configuration:

```
[ftplatinopeeyush@7.3]

; Owner
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.backlog = 1500


; User & group
user = ftplatinopeeyush
group = ftplatinopeeyush

; Listener this will placed on /run/php/ftplatinopeeyush@7.3.sock
listen=/run/php/$pool.sock

; Process Manager
pm = ondemand
; set max children
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10

pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s


; FLAGS
;php_flag[display_errors] = off
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
```

7. Open site virtual host setting

```sh
nano /path/to/virtualhost-of-wordpress.conf
```

- pointing `root` variable to `/home/ftplatinopeeyush/pathtowordpress`
- find `fastcgi_pass` (php location block)

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # split path request
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # include default configuration nginx fastcgi_params
    include fastcgi_params;
    # environment php file name
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    # try below to handle all 404 not found with script
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    # listen for cgi param port / load balancer upstream
    # port for cgi params has followed of fast cgi config
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/ftplatinopeeyush@7.3.sock;
    # handle error
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

8. Reload php & nginx service.

```sh
systemctl reload nginx.service
```

```sh
systemctl reload php7.3-fpm.service
```

9. done